# Trouble with my first latex document

Tags: compiling

Just downloaded Protex, downloaded TexStudio, and i'm trying to create a document, and i have

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin[12pt]{document}
\section{Executive Summary}

\end{document}
```

and its giving me 3 errors on the last line about it can't find the file. did i save in the wrong folder? does this work like matlab where it needs to be in a set directory first?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. What happens if you remove `[12pt]` from line 2, and put it in line 1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [12pt] is an option which belongs to the preamble of the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
 \section{Executive Summary}
 This is only test text.
\end{document}
```

This compiles without problems.

Comment: More specifically, `12pt` is an option that should be given to `\documentclass`, which resides in the document's preamble.

Answer (score 5):

When compiling a document, you do need to call `latex` (or `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, etc.) by giving it a filename that it can see, that is

- an absolute file name, like `C:\Users\Victor\Documents\summary.tex`
- a relative file name, like `summary.tex` if you're already in your `Documents` folder, or perhaps `Documents\summary.tex` if you are in your user folder (`Victor`).

TeXStudio should be taking care of this for you by default, provided you are clicking the green arrow in the toolbar.  However, your document isn't correct; `\begin` doesn't take an optional argument there.  You probably want

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Executive Summary}

\end{document}
```

which will compile without issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Executive Summary}

\end{document}
```

I think you also need to insert the
     \maketitle
 as I did in the above tex

Comment: `\maketitle` is only useful if you have actually declared a title with `\title{<your title here>}` (and perhaps `\author` and `\date`).

Comment: In fact, IIRC, the use of `\maketitle` without any of the metadata commands (`\author`, `\title`, and `\date`) is an error in the standard document classes.